# issue in start mongodb after change dbpath

Tags: mongodb

> Hi, Am editing dbpath of running mongodb in 'amazon ubuntu
>   instance'(have more than 30 GB data), and I attached some volumes I
>   for data, log, and joural

I followed [mongodb-ec2](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/platforms/amazon-ec2/#deploy-mongodb-ec2)

- mount /data , /log and /journal
- stop mongodb
- edit /etc/mongodb.conf

mongodb.conf

```
dbpath=/data
```

copy all files from old dir to new mount volumes.

- start mongodb

.
 For testing I run a python script,

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

db = MongoClient().my_testdb
```

I got the error message,

> pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure: could not connect to
>   localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused

So I remove the lock from the /data/mongod.lock.

and run sudo mongod --repair The following error I got

```
..........
ERROR: dbpath (/data/db/) does not exist
........
```

My question is, even though I configured ***dbpath=/data***, why it try to look for the path ***/data/db***? how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 3):

When you run `mongod --repair` you are not using your config file at all, so you will need to pass `--dbpath` as part of the command, e.g.:

```
mongod --dbpath /data --repair
```

Or if you wish to use the config file, run:

```
mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf --repair
```

Comment: sudo mongod --dbpath /data --repair